# put a new parent around special children

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x

I have two XML files. They are quite similar.

the first:

```
<a>
  <b />
  ...
  <c e='very important'>
    <d e='bla' />
    <d e='bla' />
  </c>
</a>
```

and the second:

```
<a>
  <f />
  ...
  <d e='some' />
  <d e='values' />
</a>
```

I have to modify the second XML, copy **c** tag from the first XML into the second one and wrap all **d** siblings there with it. I want get something like that:

```
<a>
  <f />
  ...
  <c e='very important'>
    <d e='some' />
    <d e='values' />
  </c>
</a>
```

How to do that?

**EDIT**

My attempts are scanty:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

f_tree = ET.parse(f_file)
s_tree = ET.parse(s_file)
f_root = f_tree.getroot()
s_root = s_tree.getroot()

one_c = f_root.find('c')
all_d = s_root.findall('d')

for child in one_c:
    one_c.remove(child)

for the_d in all_d:
    one_c.append(the_d)
```

Comment: Writing code is how.  Doing so before asking here is recommended.

Comment: Only thing I can solve is find the __c__ tag and all of __d__ tags. But I don't imagine how to put __c__ on right place.

Comment: @PeterNege sharing what you have done is encouraged.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Do you want to include all `<d>` tags in all `<c>` tags? Or should the number of `<d>` tags that are in the original be counted, and this number of `<d>` tags is then included in the `<c>` tag in question?

Answer (score 0):

While there may be a solution with built-in `xml.etree` which may involve looping logic or copying trees, consider an XSLT 1.0 solution using Python's third-party module, [`lxml`](http://lxml.de/).

As background, part of the XSL family which includes XPath, [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/) is a special-purpose language used to transform XML documents. XSLT maintains the [`document()`](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/func_document.asp) function allowing you to make XPath expressions across documents relative to the current XML source.

Below assumes all XML and XSL documents are in same directory. Also note, as shown XSLT scripts are well-formed XML files and can be parsed like any other XML.

**XSLT** script *(save as .xsl or .xslt file)*

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="a">
    <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:copy-of select="*[local-name()!='d']"/>       
       <c>
           <xsl:copy-of select="document('f_file.xml')/a/c/@*"/>
           <xsl:copy-of select="d"/>
       </c>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Python** script

```
import os
import lxml.etree as ET

f_tree = ET.parse('f_file.xml')
s_tree = ET.parse('s_file.xml')

xslt = ET.parse('XSLT_Script.xsl')

transform = ET.XSLT(xslt)
newdom = transform(s_tree)

# PRINT TO SCREEN
print(newdom)

# <?xml version="1.0"?>
# <a>
#   <f/>
#   <other/>
#   <c e="very important">
#     <d e="some"/>
#     <d e="values"/>
#   </c>
# </a>

# OUTPUT TO FILE
with open('Output.xml', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(newdom)
```